# Grabbing distant associations while adhering to the law of demeter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following four models:

```
#models/team.rb
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :locations
end

#models/location.rb
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  has_many :relationships
  has_many :contacts, through: :relationships
end

#models/relationship.rb
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :contact
end

#models/contact.rb
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :relationships
  has_many :locations, through: :relationships
end
```

I want to have a method on the `Team` model that I can call which grabs all of that team's associated `contacts`. Example:

```
team = Team.find 1
this_teams_contacts = team.contacts
```

I know I could define something like this within the `team` model, but it is verbose and breaks the law of demeter:

```
#models/team.rb
def contacts
  contacts_ary = []
  locations.each do |location|
    # team should not know the implementation of how location goes about grabbing contacts, thus breaking the law of demeter on the following line:
    location.contacts.each {|contact| contacts_ary << contact}
  end
  return contacts_ary
end
```

How can I grab associations that go beyond a `has_many :through` association while adhering to the law of demeter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a team `has_many :locations` and a location `has_many :contacts`, I believe you can simply add the following line to your team model:

```
has_many :contacts, through: :locations
```

And then you can retrieve the contacts for a team by simply saying `team.contacts`.  Of course there will be a lot of joining in the SQL behind the scenes in order to get there, but given your data model this is unavoidable in any case.

Comment: Wow, didn't know until your post that associations can be specified more than two tables away.  Mind blown.  Thanks!